# How to prevent Android Studio / AVD "CANNOT TRANSLATE guest DNS ip" error messages?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

About every 4 second after I start the emulator device from my Android Studio project an error message is printed into the Run window. It's extremely annoying because it hijacks the focus. If I'm in the Debug window it switches to the Run window every 4 seconds because of this error no matter what I do.

This started a day ago, but I don't know what induced it. I use the same emulator devices for several months now. Maybe an upgrade of some portion of Android SDK? The external SDK Manager is not invokable any more.

[image]

---

The messages start to come right after I boot up this API 25 wear emulator. One workaround is to make that tab float, then it doesn't hijack my focus; I move it to my second monitor.

---

I also noticed I cannot connect my Android Wear app running on my physical device (I'm running physical phone with the emulated wear) with my emulator.

Comment: Same problem. Any resolution?

Comment: Not that I know so far. Now that the external SDK manager is not available the one integrated into Andorid Studio seems like to give much less control over the bits and pieces. I don't seem have control over ARMv7 and x86 based emulators any more for example. I wanted to start my API23 wear emulator but it throws an error.

Comment: I thought I reinstall Android Studio and Android SDK to start with a clean slate. I'm on Ubuntu 16.10. I can download Android Studio, but the SDK is nowhere to be found any more. Supposedly Android Studio would contain it, but it bails out during first start looking for it. So if the Studio doesn't install it and I cannot download it separately, then I kinda stuck. I installed the Ubuntu repo's Android SDK, that is in /usr/lib/android-sdk with root privileges. Now I'm stuck

Comment: Managed to reinstall Studio & SDK

Comment: Created new wear emulators (API 23 and 25). The API 23 doesn't start, the API 25 has the same issue as in the posting.

Comment: So far I worked this around by debugging my physical Moto 360 which wasn't an easy run. Until I realized to not have the wear emulator and the physical wear active at the same time.

Comment: Which Android Studio Version  you are using ? @Csaba_Toth

Comment: @Tej, good question! v2.3.3, I'd need to try this whole scenario again with 3.x I guess

Comment: Did you try this? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64245/how-to-configure-internet-access-in-virtual-device

Comment: @Vall0n No, but I don't have any explicit proxies in my setup. First I'd like to try the project with 3.x Android Studio, but I'm bogged too much right now.

Comment: give a look to this link, it is an Android Tracked Issue.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37139091

Comment: Good reference. Last time I tried I didn't see this, but I wasn't sure if my setup (excluding Android Studio) was the same as before

Comment: I expect this to be gone with Android Studio 3.x, as others told above. I *might* have time to look at it this weekend.

Comment: @MassimilianoCatinoto Why did you delete your answer? If it works I'll mark it as the right answer. Did someone downvote it?

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are connect to a network which has a auto-redirect in it or it is **not** encrypted(HTTP). Start by

1. Disconnecting yourself from the network.
2. Restarting Android Studio

If the problem continues try posting a more detailed description of the error
If the problem doesn't continue contact your network administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

- Please make sure that you are connected to internet

**Explanation:** At startup, the emulator reads the list of DNS servers that your system is currently using. It then stores the IP addresses of up to four servers on this list and set up aliases to them on the emulated addresses `10.0.2.3`, `10.0.2.4`, `10.0.2.5` and `10.0.2.6` as needed. So, it needs internet connection to deal with them.

When starting the emulator at the command line, you can also use the `-dns-server`  option to manually specify the addresses of DNS servers to use, where `serverList` is a comma-separated list of server names or IP addresses.